# Graphstream: Set a minimum distance between Nodes

Tags: java, visualization, graphstream

I'm using graphstream to do some simple graph visualization. I've found most of the documentation helpful and easy to read, but I was unable to find a way to make sure nodes don't get too close together.

The nodes in my graph have numbers as labels, and I want to make sure that nodes don't overlap and obscure each other. Is there a simple way to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the layout attributes, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45347187/230513)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [FAQ about the layout algorithm](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/FAQ/Attributes/Is-there-a-list-of-attributes-with-a-predefined-meaning-for-the-layout-algorithms/) you can try to set a `layout.weight` attribute with value larger than 1 on the edges.